# Various Date-picker for Wicket

Tags: java, datepicker, wicket

So far I found two date-picker in wicket:

1. [org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar.DatePicker](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/extensions/yui/calendar/DatePicker.html)
2. [org.wicketstuff.dojo.markup.html.form.DojoDatePicker](http://wicketstuff.org/wicketdojo13/?wicket%3abookmarkablePage=%3aorg.wicketstuff.dojo.examples.datePicker.DatePickerShower)

The navigation for year is not present in the wicket-extensions' date-picker, also so far I found 1.3.0-beta version of wicket-stuff's date-picker, and perhaps this causes the following error messages in my console:

```
10:35:15,108 INFO  [STDOUT] 2011-05-12 10:35:15,108 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] ERROR [org.apache.wicket.request.target.resource.SharedResourceRequestTarget] - shared resource org.wicketstuff.dojo.AbstractDefaultDojoBehavior/dojo-0.4/src/i18n/calendar/nls/en-us/gregorian.js not found
10:35:15,148 INFO  [STDOUT] 2011-05-12 10:35:15,148 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] ERROR [org.apache.wicket.request.target.resource.SharedResourceRequestTarget] - shared resource org.wicketstuff.dojo.AbstractDefaultDojoBehavior/dojo-0.4/src/i18n/calendar/nls/en/gregorianExtras.js not found
10:35:15,165 INFO  [STDOUT] 2011-05-12 10:35:15,165 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] ERROR [org.apache.wicket.request.target.resource.SharedResourceRequestTarget] - shared resource org.wicketstuff.dojo.AbstractDefaultDojoBehavior/dojo-0.4/src/i18n/calendar/nls/en-us/gregorianExtras.js not found
10:35:15,242 INFO  [STDOUT] 2011-05-12 10:35:15,242 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] ERROR [org.apache.wicket.request.target.resource.SharedResourceRequestTarget] - shared resource org.wicketstuff.dojo.AbstractDefaultDojoBehavior/dojo-0.4/src/widget/nls/en/DropdownDatePicker.js not found
```

Also I heard a little about jQuery date-picker for wicket. But found no example/ demo.

I want to know is there any other date-picker for wicket available which has year navigation without bug?

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Sorry to be the one to tell you, asking for a "nice date-picker" is off-topic here. It's in the category of questions that [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) calls "every answer is equally valid."

Comment: @Lord Torgamus thanks for your suggestion. I have removed the "nice" term.

Comment: Well, the adjective wasn't really the problem; the problem is that you're asking a "list of X" question.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus, yes actually I want to know whether or not there are any other date-pickers available for wicket. And also I try to draw a little comparison between aforesaid two date-pickers.

Comment: I understand that, but the FAQ says that you're not allowed to ask that question on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an open source project for wicket components that includes a date picker component -

- http://wicket.visural.net/examples/app/dateinput